# Something wrong with Lettrine (indent ?)

Tags: indentation, lettrine

I've a problem with my lettrine.
Below i show you what's the problem :

As you can see, when i use `\begin{anything} blabla \end{anything}` the text following this block make indent without using any Lettrine.
How should i correct this ? I don't find any same issues as me ...

---

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[headheight=13.3338pt,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

% Lettrine
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{oldgerm}
\usepackage{calligra}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\calligra}

% Image
\graphicspath{ {img/} }

% Mise en page
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{page \thepage}} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
    \subsection{test}
        \subsubsection{test}
            \lettrine[lines=2, lhang=0.33, loversize=0.25, findent=1.0em]{M}{ea} culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \\\\
            Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \\ Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \begin{verbatim}
Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \end{verbatim}
            Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \\ Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
\end{document}
```

---

Edit:

Below it's exactly the same but it's my first time of use Lettrine in my document, i've tried on another document and i haven't the problem, so what's wrong with my document ?? I put exactly the same package so why \ are wrong ?
Before using \\: [image: Before]
After using \\ : [image: After]

Comment: you haven't shown any code so we have to guess but I assume you have incorrectly used the start of the lettrine paragraph in a group.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done, sorry.

Comment: Please don't post disconnected fragments, post a single complete document that shows the issue (preferably after removing all packages not needed to show the issue) but even before I try to run your fragment it is clear that all the `\\ ` are wrong and should be removed, you should almost never have `\\ `outside tables.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is simply all the spurious `\\`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[lines=2, lhang=0.33, loversize=0.25, findent=1.0em]{M}{ea} culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
\\\\
Mea culpa, mea culpa.
\\ Mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \begin{verbatim}
Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \end{verbatim}
Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
\\ Mea culpa, mea culpa.
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[lines=2, lhang=0.33, loversize=0.25, findent=1.0em]{M}{ea} culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.

Mea culpa, mea culpa.

Mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \begin{verbatim}
Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \end{verbatim}
Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.

Mea culpa, mea culpa.
\end{document}
```

Comment: When i remove "\\" the text don't go to the next line but still continue at the same line ...

Comment: @samixchoumi you need to leave a blank line as David Carlisle has done in the answer

Comment: @samixchoumi if the text is part of the same paragraph it should be on the same line. If it should be in a different paragraph then you need to make a paragraph break with a blank line as I show in the code above. So it is very rare to ever need `\\ ` in normal text.

Comment: I've tried but i'm looking on my document, and the first time i used a Lettrine, if i removed my \\ or my \\\\ the problem appear when i've no problem before

Answer (score 0):

I think i've the answer at my question, i've duplicated all my code and modified one at one the function that i used, and `\justify` is the problem but have you any idea to how justify without using `\justify` if it's in conflict with `\lettrine` ?

Comment: as noted in your previous answer please do not post non-answers as answers. This should just be a clarification of the question, preferably with updating the example to use `\justify` (but since text justification is the default `\justify` is used even less frequently than `\\ ` so it is hard to guess your real document use case here.

Comment: Do you know how can i remove the question or put a tag to explicite that this topic is resolved ? The problem is \justify so it's a new question no ?